# How to fix an SQLite Error 1 in a C# .NET Entity Framework Core Model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, unix

I am working on a console application that utilizes the C#/.NET framework called Entity Framework Core that works with SQLite database language. What this application is supposed to do, as of right now, is it outputs all of the of the categories of products that a fake company has and how many products are in each category.

Here is what the output is supposed to look like:

```
Categories and how many products they have:
Beverages has 12 products.
Condiments has 12 products.
Confections has 13 products.
Dairy Products has 10 products.
Grains/Cereals has 7 products.
Meat/Poultry has 6 products.
Produce has 5 products.
Seafood has 12 products.
```

However whenever I run the application, this is the output that I get:

```
Categories and how many products they have:
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: c.Products.Discontinuted'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.IncludeCollection(Int32 includeId, INavigation navigation, INavigation inverseNavigation, IEntityType targetEntityType, IClrCollectionAccessor clrCollectionAccessor, IClrPropertySetter inverseClrPropertySetter, Boolean tracking, Object entity, Func`1 relatedEntitiesFactory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , Category , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IncludeCompiler._Include[TEntity](QueryContext queryContext, TEntity entity, Object[] included, Action`3 fixup)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at WorkingWithEFCore.Program.QueryingCategories() in /Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/Chapter11/WorkingWithEFCore/Program.cs:line 24
   at WorkingWithEFCore.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/Chapter11/WorkingWithEFCore/Program.cs:line 12
```

Here is the code within my main file:

```
using static System.Console;
using Packt.CS7;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace WorkingWithEFCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QueryingCategories();
        }

        static void QueryingCategories()
        {
            using (var db = new Northwind())
            {
                WriteLine("Categories and how many products they have:");

                // a query to get all categories and their related products
                IQueryable<Category> cats = db.Categories.Include(c => c.Products);

                foreach (Category c in cats)
                {
                    WriteLine($"{c.CategoryName} has {c.Products.Count} products.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the file that deals with categories:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Packt.CS7
{
    public class Category
    {
        // these properties map to columns in the database
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // defines a navigation property for related rows
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public Category()
        {
            // to enable developers to add products to a Category we must
            // initiate the navigation property to an empty list
            this.Products = new List<Product>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that deals with the products:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Packt.CS7
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [Column("UnitPrice", TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

        [Column("UnitsInStock")]
        public short? Stock { get; set; }

        public bool Discontinuted { get; set; }

        // these two define the foriegn key relationship
        // to the Category table
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the code that connects to the database:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Packt.CS7
{

    // this manages the connect to the database
    public class Northwind : DbContext
    {
        // these properties map to tables in the database
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // to use SQLite, uncomment the following
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Northwind.db");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // example of using Fluent API instead of attributes 
            // to limit the length of a category name to under 40
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .Property(category => category.CategoryName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that you dont have column (`c.Products.Discontinuted`) in your table

Comment: I found the problem, there was a typo on line 20 of the products.cs file.