# Failure to Execute the DBCommand: SQLite Err. 1 - C# / .NET / Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After performing a *migrations scaffold* with the .NET CLI for *EF migrations*, there is a continual error in the terminal output where the SQLite extension already sees an existing table with the same name that was passed to the `dotnet ef database update` command.

Whenever the database attempts to be created, the following console output keeps occurring:

> SQLite Error 1: "table 'table_name' already exists."

[DbCommand Failure: SQLite Err #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMSm.png)

Attempts to resolve:

- Reverting to previous migrations before rebuilding database with `dotnet ef database update` command.
- Adding "0" flag to revert to previous migration instance with `dotnet ef database update 0` command.
- Removing scaffold with `dotnet ef migrations remove` command.
- Rebuilding with `dotnet ef migrations add -o` command for appropriate current working directory.
- Reinstalling *dotnet ef* framework.

Also, reference to this following author on StackOverflow did not apply for this particular issue:

[How to fix an SQLite Error 1 in a C# .NET Entity Framework Core Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847744/how-to-fix-an-sqlite-error-1-in-a-c-sharp-net-entity-framework-core-model)

The "hoped for" outcome for reverting or rebuilding is for a clean migrations scaffold in case that may be the cause for duplication.

Also, not sure if related, but null references have been "disabled" in the API file that .NET requires for this project.

Comment: Delete all of your previous migration script along with initial script and make sure your database is empty and execute the migration command again.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron -  The'dotnet ef migrations remove' command performs this action, unless what you are suggesting is further in depth.There is an additional 'drop-database' command which returns an error of bad syntax! https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations#:~:text=To%20use%20migrations%20in%20EF%20Core%2C%20you%20start,changes%20you%20have%20made%20to%20your%20database%20schema. Would you please clarify?  Also, since SQLite cannot create the database from the "Source" file, does that mean the database is already empty?